# http response return type deserialization into a specific type

Tags: json, wcf, rest

i want to De-serialize stream body received from a HTTP web request as a response.but the problem is that when De-serialize has to be done as a specific type. i have multiple Get's and they have different responses(one returns type p, other returns type q). i want to have a generalized method which De-serializes any type and return me something generalized which when type caste would return me the required value.

Comment: I can have try catch block and try to deserialize it in it but it would be a bad programming practice.what other options do i have?

Answer (score 0):

The magic sauce is knowing which type to populate.  Once you have that, creating a generic deserializer is pretty easy:

```
public object Deserialize( string serialized, Type T ) {
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( serialized ) ) {
        return null;
    }
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer( T );
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( StringToBytes( s ) ?? new byte[0] );
    XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter( ms, Encoding.UTF8 );
    return xs.Deserialize( ms );
}
```

It's also easy to turn this into a generic method.

Comment: Well there was no other option for me to find out the type being returned. So what i did was i added an HTTP Header('ResponseType') which carried the type of the object returned in the response in the service side.On the client side i just checked the response header and deserialized it accordingly.